# Need to format a string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string

I have to format the addresses of my application in to a format like below using a single string.

```
1421 COUNTRY CLUB RD    
PO BOX 953  
CAMDEN  
USA
```

But I have different columns in my table for each fields.

[image]

I have to format them into a single string and display like this..

```
Address1
Address2
Address3
City
ZIPCode
County
State
Country
```

So far what I have done is I format them into a string in my Model

```
 public string DisplayShippingAddress
        {
            get { return string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6} {7}", this.Address1, this.Address2, this.Address3,this.City,this.ZIPCode, this.County,this.State,this.Country); }
        }
```

But I get a single line string.I need to format it just like above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To split a string across lines, you just use the newline character: '\n'

```
get { return string.Format("{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n{3}\n{4}\n{5}\n{6}\n{7}", this.Address1, this.Address2, this.Address3,this.City,this.ZIPCode, this.County,this.State,this.Country); }
```

Most controls aren't multiline by default, so make sure to turn it on in whatever you are using to output this.

Answer (score 2):

Since it is one line per value I would look at doing it like this:

```
public string DisplayShippingAddress
{
    get
    {
        return String.Join(Environment.NewLine, new []
        {
            this.Address1, this.Address2, this.Address3,
            this.City, this.ZIPCode, this.County,
            this.State, this.Country
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public string DisplayShippingAddress
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n{3}\n{4}\n{5}\n{6}\n{7}", this.Address1, this.Address2, this.Address3,this.City,this.ZIPCode, this.County,this.State,this.Country); }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

User Environment.Newline which will insert a new line wherever you want.

```
var addressFormat = this.Address1 +Environment.Newline+this.Address2+Environment.Newline;
```